# Grouping things in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel:

```
1 5
1 6
2 7
3 9
4 9
4 2
```

I need to compute sums from values in the second column,
that have the same value in the first column. This is the desired result:

```
1 11
2 7
3 9
4 11
```

Can this be done in Excel?

Comment: OK but how is the question, yes does not help much :)

Comment: `OK but how is the question, yes does not help much :)` well, I do not see a "how" in your question...:) You might want to see [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Currently, your question might attract lot of "DownVotes" unless you do something about it

Comment: You edited your initial answers after I flagged you. Now you play smart by "examining" my profile and getting conclusions that fit you. In the mean time an answer was posted to the answer. Don't know why you are here in the first place.

Comment: You flagged me? For pointing you to the Meta? This is hilarious...

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. Questions about software functionality are better-suited to [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using pivot tables. Place a label above both columns. Select the data and add a pivot table. Select the first column as row labels and place the second column in the sum field. Make sure that field is displayed as sum of values.

For instance:

```
Category Value
1         5
1         6
2         7
3         9
4         9
4         2
```

- Select all your data incl. the headers.
- Click insert --> pivot table
- Drag 'Category' to the row labels field
- Drag 'Value' to the 'Values' field
- Make sure it is displayed as 'Sum of value'
- If not, click it --> Value field settings --> Summarize values as 'Sum'

Note that the labels above your columns are needed because excel requires named columns when making pivot tables.

Comment: Can you provide more details please? This is not enough for me, I am not expert in excel.

Comment: Added some more details. Is it clear now? Make sure to upvote/accept when you understand the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I wait for time to pass to accept the answer.