# Adding values in column only where two other values in previous columns are known

Tags: excel

I have a file with thousands of rows where I need to add the 3rd column for a specific set of values in the previous columns.  for example:

Col1---Col2---Col3
a--------#--------1
a--------#--------3
a--------#--------5
a--------$--------2
a--------$--------4
a--------$--------6
b--------#--------2.5
b--------#--------2.5
b--------#--------2.5

So I need to end up with a condensed version that has:

Col1---Col2---Col3
a--------#--------9
a--------$--------12
b--------#--------7.5

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!!

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, could you be more specific. What do you mean with condensed version and what do you mean with all those a $ 4 etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping things in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905422/grouping-things-in-excel)

Comment: Also try a pivot table - this is exactly what they are for.

Comment: Thanks everybody! The pivot table did the trick! and yes, this was very similar to "Grouping things in Excel"

Answer (score 0):

you can use =SUMIFS(Col3, Col1,"a",Col2,"#") in your third column.

You can reference instead of the "a" and "#" directly